why I can't use adaptive performance in unity? "Holder.Instance" is always null
component in unity
debug log in unity
void Start()
{
    ap = Holder.Instance;
    if(ap == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("error ap");
        return;
    }
    if (!ap.Active)
        return;

    QualitySettings.lodBias = 1.0f;
    ap.ThermalStatus.ThermalEvent += OnThermalEvent;
}

why no active loader was found? what can i do? error version? error package?
I have reinstall many times. I wish I can code based on Adaptive Performance

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
